# What could cause my old gas furnace to keep cutting out?

Tags: furnace

I have a old gas furnace that keeps cutting out. It turns on and the when it hits the temp it turns off and then when it turns on it will not give it gas. It will just sound like it blowing but no air comes out of the vents. And I can't see any flame in the furnace. I have had an repair guy come out and all he did was hit the little reset switch in the furnace and it fixed it. For a little while at lest, now I have to do it at lest once a day. I don't know what is wrong. I don't what to keep calling someone out to just hit the reset switch. Dose anyone know what is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I would check your ignition sensor or your flame sensor. There are also heat switches that "melt" and shut off to stop the furnace from catching fire. I had a similar problem when I bought my house that was a foreclosure. The furnace sat for a while and the sensor got covered in dust and burnt out when I turned the heat on. The best way to figure out what's up is to remove the cover and look for some blinking lights. It will depend on the furnace type. These lights will give you a code that will help you figure out what the real problem is. So 
Google your furnace model and how to find the code 
then 
Google your furnace model and the code to get an idea of the problem

Comment: +1, clean the flame sensor with some fine grit sand paper. On some models the exhaust blower will run continuously while nothing else is happening; this can indicate a failed safety switch.